# Passing asynchronous data to directive every 5 seconds

Tags: angularjs

**Controller**

```
angular.module('App').controller('reportsController',function($scope,$interval,$http){
    $scope.reportsObj = {
       retorts:[]
    }
    $scope.getReports = () => {
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/getReports'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
             $scope.reportsObj.reports = response;
          }, function errorCallback(error) {
           console.log(error);
        });
    }
    $interval(() => {
        $scope.getReports();
    },5000)
})
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('App').directive('reportsDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:"E",
      scope:{
        reportsObj:"="
      },
      templateUrl:"./reports-analytics.html",
      link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        console.log("reports",scope.reportsObj.reports);
        scope.$watch('reportsObj',function(val){
          console.log(val);
        },true)
      }
    }
})
```

Markup:usage

```
<reports-directive></reports-directive>
```

reports-analytics.html

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="report in reports">{{report.val}}</li>
</ul>
```

i tried this way, it doesn't seem to work,
is this a best practice? i am new to angularjs, i appreciate if you guide me in a right way.

Comment: reportsController is the controller of your view right? & not the controller of directive?
And in that view you're using the directive <reports-directive></reports-directive> correct?

Comment: yes u r right, and i removed  
scope:{
    reportsObj:"="
  }
it is working now don't know wt is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are three types of scopes in custom directive, i.e. Shared, inherited, isolated. 
If you don't use `scope:{ reportsObj:"=" }` means it's a shared scope directive, it'll share scope of controller in which it's used. And that's why it'll work what you're expecting.

With another approach,
Using isolated scope just like what you've used, update directive code as follows:

```
angular.module('App').directive('reportsDirective',function(){
return {
  scope:{
    reportsObj:"="
  },
  templateUrl:"./reports-analytics.html",
  link: function(scope,element,attrs){
    // directive logic
  }
 }
})
```

And update the use of directive in reportsController view as :

```
<reports-directive reports-obj="reportsObj "></reports-directive>
```

Don't change code of `reportsController`  & `reports-analytics.html`. This should also work as expected. But because of the use of '=' if you change reportsObj inside directive its value will change in outside controller also.

Plunker **[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/U05fnr4gGf9UV8IRYz9r?p=preview)**.